# Set flash message after redirect

Tags: controller, flash

I’m trying to display a flash message in the CP after being redirect from a controller.

Some context: when a user registers from a front-end, the account is set to “pending” and the admin gets a notification email. Inside the email, there’s a link “Activate this user” pointing to a controller action that performs the activation and redirect to the user CP page.

So far, so good! But I’d like to show a notification that tells the admin that the user has been activated. So my controller is something like this…

```
public function actionActivateUser() {

    $this->requireAdmin();

    // get the user and perform activation...

    $this->setSuccessFlash('Activation mail sent');
    return $this->redirect('admin/users/' . $user->id);
}
```

Activation works ok, but no message is shown. I’ve tried a few alternative methods like `setFlash()` or `addFlash()` without success. Am I missing something?

Thank you!

UPDATE: The flash message is set, if I redirect to a front-end template it gets displayed correctly, but CP pages ignore it. However, this works:

```
Craft::$app->session->addJsFlash(" Craft.cp.displayNotice('Activation email sent') ");
```

But I'm pretty sure it's not the right way to do it.

Comment: This should work. It might just be from your copy/paste but there is an apostrophe `’` after the word _sent_ instead of a single quote `'`, is that the problem?

Comment: Just a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In a controller method, `setNotice` works for me for this sort of thing.

```
Craft::$app->getSession()->setNotice(Craft::t('my-plugin', 'Activation mail sent'));
```

Comment: Tried, but unfortunately nothing changes.